# MongoDB throws "ns does not exist" after creating validator in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So I am trying to create validator in MongoDB using Python, when I run my code it throws error like this one

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: ns does not exist.

```py
book_validator = {some data}
production.create_collection("")
production.command("collMod", "book", validator=book_validator)
```

I found out that after runing the code it creates collection. But I would like to know what is causes the error. But validator is not created. I found similar problem here in some question but it was unsolved an few years old, so hopefully someone knows answer by now.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code shows how to create / update a validator using [`db.command()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command)

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
my_db = client['mydatabase']
my_coll = 'mycollection'

my_validator = {
    '$jsonSchema': {
        'bsonType': 'object',
        'required': ['name'],
        'properties': {
            'name': {
                'bsonType': 'string',
                'minLength': 4,
                'maxLength': 20,
                'description': 'must be a string (4 to 20 chars) and is required'
            }
        }
    }
}


def update_validator(db, collection, validator):
    query = {'collMod': collection,
             'validator': validator,
             'validationLevel': 'strict',
             'validationAction': 'error'
             }

    db.command(query)


update_validator(my_db, my_coll, my_validator)
```